# How to choose the data that I want in my stacked bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

It's been a while.

I would like to plot a stacked bar plot with months on the x axis and values on the y axis.

My dataframe looks like this, but I have around 90 rows.

EDIT FOR THE SAMPLE OF THE DATA:

```
data <- data.frame(
  x = sample(c("a","b"), 24, replace = TRUE),
  y = sample(c("a","b","c","d"), 24, replace = TRUE),
  z = sample(1:24)
)
```

I think something like this should do the trick to make an approximation.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The numbers variable's value is to be represented on the bars and the XDURAC values are to be represented as text over the bars.

Basically, I want something like that plot but with the "19DURAC" value (5.04, for example) over the "19" bar of march, not being represented as a bar.

To make this dfr adn plot I used this code:

```
durac_v3 <- durac_v2
library("reshape", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.5")
durac_v3$MESES <- row.names(durac_v3)
mdfr <- melt(as.data.frame(durac_v3, id.vars="MESES"))

library(scales)
p <- ggplot(mdfr, aes(mdfr$MESES, value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

**Well, here comes a big edit. Sorry for the mess, guys, It's been a long time since I used R or stack. Read from here**

The dataframe will be this:

```
data <- data.frame(
  x = sample(c(1:12), 80, replace = TRUE),
  y = sample(c("19","19DURAC","50","50DURAC","PUSH","PUSHDURAC","GRATIS","GRATISDURAC"), 80, replace = TRUE),
  z = sample(1:80)
)
```

Where `x` will be the months in the year (1: january, 12: december), `y`a classification variable (names of states, for example) and z its values (time spent doing something for every word with the `DURAC` ending and number of people for every other).

First, I want a stacked bar plot where the months are on the `x` axis.
Secondly, for my `y` column, my bars will only represent the values of the data without the `DURAC`ending. This means, `19`, `50`, `PUSH` and `GRATIS`.
Third, I want the `19DURAC` values represented as annotations over the `19` part of the bar, the `50DURAC`values over the `50`, and so on and so on.

Again, if I do not explain myself, I am so sorry. I am a bit rusty.

**OUTPUT OF DPUT**

```
dput(head(mdfr))
structure(list(MESES = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("19", "19DURAC", "50", "50DURAC", 
"PUSH", "PUSHDURAC", "GRATIS", "GRATISDURAC"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(NA, NA, 1431, 982, 766, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please post a representative sample of your data, preferably the output of `dput`, not a picture of it

Comment: Why not just subset the data in being passed to ggplot2? `ggplot(mdfr[mdfr$MESES != "19",], aes(mdfr$MESES, value, ...`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, don't use $ inside the aes. ggplot will find the variable in the data.frame

Comment: Thank you for your comments, guys.
Answering to you, JMT2080AD, it gives me a "FALSE" and "TRUE"  result. Your approach is good (I don't know why I didn't think about it).

Comment: I think you should edit this so the question relates to the sample simulated data you've now added.  It's not clear to me how to use the sample simulated data.  But I also really don't understand the basic question " I want something like that plot but with the "19DURAC" value (5.04, for example) over the "19" bar of march".  Do you mean you want the actual value on the plot as an annotation, rather than as a bar?

Comment: Yes, you got it right. That is exactly what I need. Sorry I didn't explain myself.
About the edit, I will at night. (08:00 here)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with using `dplyr` instead of `reshape` the following solution should work based on the picture of the data set you shared

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)
durac_v3 %>% 
  group_by(MESES, variable) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(MESES, value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  geom_text(aes(x = MESES, y = value, label = value), position = "fill", vjust = 2)
```

Comment: I tried with your suggestion. Although I would love it to work, It does not. It keeps plotting the "xDURAC" data like a bar. I want it only as an annotation. But I already editted my question, so now I think I explained myself better. Again, I am sorry.